# Typescript interface with multiple named functions

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain how if the below will type to a object that holds 2 functions? I can't find the docs on something like this.

```
interface FooContext {
  bar(a: A, b: B[]): boolean;
  baz(a: A, b: B[]): boolean;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question but hope the following helps: an interface doesn't have objects, it has classes that implements it and these classes will have objects (instances)

Comment: Doesn't an interface type to an object though?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, here are three [examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0GF3ggDzAB4BBAGmQCEA+ZAbwChlkAjOKACjgC5lzXelANoBdAJS8WmADYQ4IANxNWcAF5de-FoNETWMuYoYBfBgwS4AzmGQE4AWwAOsgIy8M2XJEJEQAV3sWaAprKFAAc1oAXnplZjZOOAoWMXooCDA-KBBkeGlLCGMyOJV1JNZUunTM7OQwKD9CkzMEaThLS2QAUXwHZwgAJmRgJ1l7CHBOjxw8H1CIin9A6FpGZmZHPxZpYAQVRN55kHDk3iWgqF00jKycvILjJXXkTe3d0o1kI5OBZHPoK5VG61eqNUymcxWGx2UaDdyYGbeYjfRYBC7RP4QADu3V6sIGHDESgYAHoSaBILBECgwAALOA2AAmEEsCDCQU6cFyfhACDAwFwAFp0CwAFYQPkMCnQeBINA8vkCkAASTwVLla2QhMkBnkSghFhA1lseP6AGZ3Ar+bhVZTZSgYoTkFFaKCIAogA) of how an interface would resolve into real objects:

```
interface FooContext<A, B> {
  bar(a: A, b: B[]): boolean;
  baz(a: A, b: B[]): boolean;
}

const example1: FooContext<number, string> = {
    bar(a, b) {return false},
    baz(a, b) {return true}
}

class Example2 implements FooContext<string, number> {
    public bar(a: string, b: number[]) {return false};
    public baz(a: string, b: number[]) {return true}
}

const example2: FooContext<string, number> = new Example2();

//interface that describes a function-object
interface FunctionInterface {
  (): boolean;
}

const example3: FunctionInterface = () => true;
```

An interface can describe any kind of object, be it an instantiated object of a class or a simple object itself. Keep in mind that arrays, functions, classes, and so on are all objects themself in javascript and can also be described by an interface.

Comment: You simply assume that the OP actually uses a templated interface? Perhaps types `A` and `B` are defined in a completely different way. (You might be right though, but the OP didn't provide that info explicitly.)

Answer (score 1):

Your interface `FooContext` defines two methods: `bar` and `baz`. But it also defines the exact *signature* of those two methods: both the `bar` and `baz` functions take two parameters, the first one of type `A` and the second one of type `B[]`, and they both return a value of type `boolean`.

Any object that provides at least those two methods with those signatures will comply with your `FooContext` interface.